# How to load an external URL on PhoneGap/Cordova and have PushNotifications enabled?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

What i am trying to do is make an iOS PhoneGap/Cordova application that , the only thing it does is load an external URL and have PushNotifications Enabled.

It seems that i can do both separately but not both together.

For the PushNotifications i am using a plugin , which seems to work great.

However when i try to open an external URL from my index.html , the PushNotification doesnt work.

I am using this tutorial to enable Push [iOS PhoneGap/Cordova Push](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/).

And after i download the sample code i am trying to use something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

        <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for Cordova to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // Cordova is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
                ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
            }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i include the scripts index.js and pushnotifications.js that are needed to enable the push.

But i can only see the URL loading and the push is not enabled.

If i try this , the push is enabled :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
        <title>Push Notification Tester</title>
        <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("Test " + app);
            app.initialize();
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But of course in this example , i am not using an external Url as i would like. So how would i add on this code the external Url function to have both external url and push ?

Any ideas?